# Combine two CSS classes into one

Tags: css, less

I have this code:

```
[class*="-something"], [class*="Others"] {
    //change some UI
}
```

As it can be seen, there are two conditions for whom the UI is modified.

I wonder if there is a way to combine them into one. I tried this but it seems it's not the right way:

```
[class*="-something || Others"] {
    //change some UI
}
```

Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: The first code is the way to go. No alternative possible with pure CSS

Comment: but is it possible with LESS?

Comment: Why? Is the latter significantly easier for some reason?

Comment: It's possible with LESS, but it'd take so much plumbing as to be a waste of time compared to what you already have.